# RN4020 Bluetooth simple data transfer service

Tags: bluetooth

I want to transfer data from my Smartphone to the RN4020 Bluetooth module. The easiest way is to use MLDP service. But I don't want to use it as CMD/MLDP pin is connected to +3.3V. And the only way to exit from the MLDP mode is power off/on. Which is not suitable for me.

That's why I'm looking for another way. 
It should be possible via private services.

Could you please provide me with the example code?

RN4020 documentation doesn't have the detailed information for that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm able to do that using private service and SUW command.
Now I'm investigating the details.

Comment: Could you share your code for connecting to a private service, please? Thanks!!

Comment: Would interest me too :P